# Rust Rocket, how to Access Data from a Request URI Query

Tags: rust, request, query-string, rust-rocket

I'm busy working with a Rust Rocket application and I was wondering if it is possible to access the data from a Request URI Query object from inside of a FromRequest implementation.

I have an example FromRequest implementation as

```
use rocket;
use rocket::{Config, Rocket, FromForm};
use rocket::request::{FromRequest, Request, Outcome};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let figment = Config::figment().merge(("address", "0.0.0.0")).merge(("port", 31));
    let _rocket = Rocket::build()
        .configure(figment)
        .mount("/", rocket::routes![index])
        .launch().await.expect("ERROR");
}

#[rocket::get("/")]
fn index(_query_params:QueryParams) -> &'static str {
    return "Index";
}

#[derive(FromForm)]
pub struct QueryParams { _nothing:String }

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for QueryParams {
    type Error = rocket::Error;
    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        // get the query object
        let query = request.uri().query().unwrap();
        // check the contents of the query
        println!("{:?}", query);
        // below does not work because they are private fields
        let data_value = query.data.value;
        Outcome::Success(QueryParams { _nothing:String::from("nothing") })
    }
}
```

Using `rocket = "0.5.0-rc.2"`

If I do a test get request as

```
http://url.com:31/?param01%5Bkey01%5D=val01&param01%5Bkey02%5D=val02
```

I can get the following with the Debug Output

```
Query { source: None, data: Data { value: "param01%5Bkey01%5D=val01&param01%5Bkey02%5D=val02", decoded_segments: [uninitialized storage] } }
```

I can see the value is there and looks correct but I can't find any way of accessing it at this point because they are behind private fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For version 0.4: Use [the `Iterator` implementation](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/request/struct.Query.html#impl-Iterator) to get a sequence of [`FormItem`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/request/struct.FormItem.html)s, which have public fields `raw`, `key`, and `value` of type [`RawStr`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/http/struct.RawStr.html).

For version 0.5-rc: Use the methods on Query listed here: https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/http/uri/struct.Query.html#impl, or, since [it `Deref`s to `RawStr`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/http/uri/struct.Query.html#deref-methods-RawStr), you can use any of `RawStr`'s methods.

Comment: I see the documentation is for Rocket 0.4, I'm just updating my question to specify the Rocket version but I don't suppose you can elaborate on an example? I'm very new to Rust

Comment: @TheLovelySausage I've added information about 0.5-rc to my answer. If you provide information about what you're trying to do with the query string, I can help out more.

Comment: Calling `as_str()` on the Query object was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!